# Dynamically load fancybox and attach it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I am trying to dynamically load fancybox via getScript and then attach it to a element. I have the fancybox dynamically load inside of a document ready...

So it goes.

```
documents ready -> getScript
```

But it doesn't seem to want to attach to my a tag (`.fancybox`) if I do a console.log `jQuery('.fancybox')` I get a [] but the element is already loaded? And if I type in `jQuery('.fancybox').fancybox();` in the console in Google Chrome it still doesn't work?

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
jQuery.getScript("/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js", function() {
      console.log(jQuery(".fancybox"),jQuery("a"));
      return jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
```

The element is a simple a tag wrapping an image, and it is NOT dynamically loaded.

```
<div class="youtube"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1svYgdfgfdf" class="fancybox"><img height="181" src="images/youtube-video.png" width="326"></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document ready is too early try wrapping it in `$(window).load(function(){//CODE HERE});` instead because it needs to run only after DOM has loaded so it can apply your fancybox to your DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery.getScript("/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js", function() {
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox();
  });
});
```

**EDIT:** function call fixed

Comment: Your solution make sense, however your functions are not properly closed. It would worth a revision of your code ;)